UML Actor, UseCase and BehavioredClassifiers
Both UML Actor and UseCase specialize BehavioredClassifier which implies that they can own Behaviors. It is clear to me that UseCase needs to have Behaviors in order to link itself to StateMachine or Activity. But what about Actor?
Can anyone give me an example of an Actor with some kind of Behavior? I haven't stumbled across one yet.

No, I haven't seen Actors with behaviors either.
However, a use case describes also actions of the actors. So, we really expect the actors to have some behavior.
Usually we describe this behavior somehow in the behavior of the use case. This description is rather informal. If we wanted to be more formal, the actor itself could have the behavior. I have not seen the necessity to do it, but formally it does make sense.
Of course, there is the problem, that an actor can be involved in many use cases, and there is no way to specify, which of its behaviors belongs to which use case.

@Axel Scheithauer - Thank you! In the meantime, I was wondering about a UseCase defined by a sequence diagram, i.e. an Interaction, and its initial message comes from an Actor -- for example, when the user clicks a button or selects a menu item in the GUI of an application. Does the Actor need to have a Behavior in order to send an initial call message?

No, the actor doesn't need a modeled behavior. The interaction can specify that the actor sends a message. Of course, this implies that the actor in reality does have a behavior, it's just not modeled.

As per the UML specifications, the actor is external to the system. Its behavior does thus not need to be modelled.
The actor is deemed to have some behavior, even if it is not specified, because some behavior is needed to interact with the system under consideration.
